# Node reference - show parent node when viewing child

Tags: 7, views

I'm using [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module. I have parent node where I can choose multiple child nodes for it. This parent has reference-field. 
I have made views to list child nodes when viewing parent node.

Now I need to have views to show parent node when viewing child node.

This should be fairly easy to do(?), but I was not able to achieve it. 
I tried with reverse reference relationship, but it does not show nothing on child page.

How to show parent node (in views) when viewing child node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one content type view with views module,

Set **relationship >> Content: Reference node** (field_reference_node)

In **contextual filter >> Content: Nid (relationship field_reference_node)**

Pass NID of child node within argument will result all node referenced with parent content.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use Entity reference module? I dont have field Entity fields in my Views: (choose Entity Reference: Referenced Entity)

Comment: no with reference module itself can be possible check edited answer

Comment: Okey. What settings should I use in Contextual filter? I have added field Content: Nid. What to choose for: "When the filter value is NOT available"? Tried with "Display all results for the specified field" and "Provide default value: Content ID from URL". But it is showing all childs, not parents.

Comment: what you added in relationship?

Comment: I have added Reference field which is in Parent node: "Content: Reference".

Comment: now set content:reference relationship in contextual field on content:Nid

Comment: Yes, I have Relationship set in Contextual filter for "Content: Nid". What kind of settings should I have in Contextual filter "When the filter value is NOT available" etc?

Comment: in contextual filter of that field there is setting for no result set **Display contents of "No results found"** when no argument pass

Comment: I had relationship set in Fields Title and thats why it was showing child node titles for me (I forgotted this testing earlier). Now it works! Thank you.